# attach mdf and ldf file to sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

hi friends i have mdf and ldf file for database. I am going to attach this files to sql server 2012 but this error is occured:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Attach database failed for Server 'IMAN-PC\TESTSQL'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>   For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.3000.0+((SQL11_PCU_Main).121019-1325+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Attach+database+Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GISTrec.FileStrem". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".
>
> A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\GISTrec.FileStrem' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
>   Could not open new database 'GISTrec'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5120)
>
> For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.2100&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5120&LinkId=20476

what can I do for attaching this file?